# accessing spidev with major number greater than 8 bits

Tags: python, linux, linux-device-driver, spi

I'm working with a Zynq board with an ARM v7, have [`petalinux`](https://www.quora.com/What-is-PetaLinux) installed on it. There are 2 SPI devices, `/dev/spidev32765.0` and `/dev/spidev32766.0`. I'm try using [`libsoc`](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc) `python` bindings to access the devices. During a SPI read/write I'm getting the following error:

```
spidev spi32765.0: SPI transfer timed out
```

[`libsoc`](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc) allows [to enable a debugging](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/blob/master/bindings/python/spi.py#L60) output, which I did.

Here is the output with debugging enabled:

```
libsoc_spi.LibsocSPITestCase.test_write
libsoc-debug: debug enabled (libsoc_set_debug)
libsoc-spi-debug: initialising spidev device 32765.0 (NULL, libsoc_spi_init)
libsoc-spi-debug: setting mode to 1 (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_set_mode)
libsoc-spi-debug: read mode as 1 (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_get_mode)
libsoc-spi-debug: setting speed to 125000Hz (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_set_speed)
libsoc-spi-debug: read speed as 125000Hz (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_get_speed)
libsoc-spi-debug: setting bits per word to 8 (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_set_bits_per_word)
libsoc-spi-debug: read bits per word as 8 (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_get_bits_per_word)
libsoc-spi-debug: performing write transfer of 3 bytes (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_write)
spidev spi32765.0: SPI transfer timed out
libsoc-spi-debug: failed sending message (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_write)
libsoc-spi-debug: freeing spi device (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_free)
```

I have a few questions with respect to `spidev` and the debugging output.

1. Take a look at the following line: `libsoc-spi-debug: initialising spidev device 32765.0 (NULL, libsoc_spi_init)`. 
   According to [this](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/blob/master/lib/include/libsoc_spi.h#L22) `spidev` is a `uint8_t`. So how come [this](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/blob/master/lib/spi.c#L51) treats as if it is a `uint16_t`?
2. Take a look at the following line: `libsoc-spi-debug: setting mode to 1 (spidev253.0, libsoc_spi_set_mode)`. 
   Spidev is set to `253.0`. I don't have any `spidev` devices with that number. How come the code didn't fail [here](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/blob/master/lib/spi.c#L75) and [here](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/blob/master/lib/spi.c#L77)? If I don't have a `spidev` with this number how come it managed to open a file descriptor to it?
3. Can there be `spidev` devices with a major number greater than 255? If it isn't then how come I have one? Is it possible to change it to a major number that is withing the range of 255?

Any help on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: You just need to check the latest version of binding you are using, if there is still a problem, file a bug against that library. JFYI: https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc/pull/79

Comment: @0andriy Yeah, I saw that. I used that fork and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Perhaps best place is to continue discussion there, you may put your comment to let author know that it doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: @0andriy I don't think it is an issue with the `libsoc`. I think it is driver issue.

Comment: How come? What the exact problem driver does have by your opinion? (by the way it's an SPI core which assigns those numbers, not the particular driver)

Comment: @0andriy The code that I wrote works with no issues on a Raspberry PI. I'm working with a custom board with Zynq FPGA and an ARM v7 processor. That's what led me to say it is a driver issue. And when I said driver, I should have said driver and hardware combination. But my questions are still even if my code doesn't work on the Zynq platform.

Comment: The libsoc will not work on majority x86 SoCs by very same reason, numbers there are dynamically chosen, while RPi has them static. It has nothing to do with hardware, and you need to go to that bug report and continue there. I'm done here.